# Object.assign() and array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, spread-syntax

I have a nested array like this

```
const names= [[{name: "John"}, {name: "Mary"}],
           [{name: "Paul"}, {name: "Peter"}]];
```

I would like inject `country` into the nested object

```
const country = {country :"USA"}
```

so that output looks like

```
[{name: "John", country : "USA"}, {etc} ,{etc} ]
```

The code idea have is something like this

```
const combined = names.map((map)=> 
       Object.assign({}, 
              country, 
              /*something to extract name from nested array names*/),
       {country}
         )
```

Any suggestions how i could spread the object in the nested array to form the desired output?

If the code could be improved in other ways, please let me know as well

Comment: Should `country` be add to all array elements or just the first element in the nested array?

Comment: So you want to add another key to every object? But is the expected output a similarly nested array of objects or just a flat array of objects? And should the old objects and arrays be reused? And will the array be always nested exactly one level deep?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to create a new array with all sub-array elements concatenated before using [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) like the following way:

```js
const names= [[{name: "John"}, {name: "Mary"}],
           [{name: "Paul"}, {name: "Peter"}]];
const country = {country :"USA"}
const combined = names.flat().map(p => Object.assign(p, country));
console.log(combined);
```

Answer (score 2):

Make use of reduce to flatten your array along with map and object.assign to add the country value to each object

```js
const names= [[{name: "John"}, {name: "Mary"}],
           [{name: "Paul"}, {name: "Peter"}]];
const country = {country :"USA"};
const newNames = names.reduce((acc, item) =>{
    acc= acc.concat(item.map(value => Object.assign({}, value, country)));
    return acc;
},[]);
console.log(newNames);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's about using a nested `map` in an outer `map`:

```js
const names = [
  [{
    name: "John"
  }, {
    name: "Mary"
  }],
  [{
    name: "Paul"
  }, {
    name: "Peter"
  }]
]

const country = { country: 'USA' }

const output = names.map (xs => xs.map (x => ({ ...x, ...country })))

console.log (output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might declare a new array literal, list `country` as the first item, then *spread* the `names[0]` array into it, no need for `Object.assign` nor `.map` if you only have one sub-array:

```js
const names= [[{name: "John"}, {name: "Mary"}],
           [{name: "Paul"}, {name: "Peter"}]];
const country = {country :"USA"};
const newNames = [[country, ...names[0]]];
console.log(newNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can double map the names array and it's nested array and destructure country into each item.

```js
const names = [[{name: "John"}, {name: "Mary"}],
           [{name: "Paul"}, {name: "Peter"}]];
           
const country = {country :"USA"};

const namesWithCountry = names.map(name => name.map(n => ({...n, ...country})));

console.log(namesWithCountry);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.flatMap()` to flatten the arrays returned by the inner `.map()` method:

```js
const names= [[{name: "John"}, {name: "Mary"}], [{name: "Paul"}, {name: "Peter"}]],
res = names.flatMap(arr => arr.map(elem => ({...elem, country: 'USA'})));

console.log(res);
```