# Object.assign for an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, array-map

So I'm able to use object.assign on an object like this

```js
let recipe = {"recipeId":1,"title":"Instant Pot® Chicken and Wild Rice Soup","directions":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit","imageLink":"https://images-gmi-pmc.edge-generalmills.com/60c3ebda-50a7-415e-8c66-14f6c9b93034.jpg","id":"1"}
this.editableRecipe = Object.assign({},recipe);
```

but i'm having trouble doing this with a list of objects like this:

```js
let ingredients = [
    {"ingredientId":1,"amount":1,"unit":"package","ingredient":"(20 oz) boneless skinless chicken thighs","note":"patted dry","id":"1"},
    {"ingredientId":2,"amount":1,"unit":"teaspoon","ingredient":"salt22323","note":"","id":"2"},
    {"ingredientId":3,"amount":0.5,"unit":"teaspoon","ingredient":"pepper","note":"","id":"3"},
    {"ingredientId":4,"amount":2,"unit":"tablespoons","ingredient":"butter","note":"","id":"4"},
    {"ingredientId":5,"amount":1,"unit":"package","ingredient":"(20 oz) boneless skinless chicken thighs","note":"patted dry","id":"5"},
    {"ingredientId":6,"amount":1,"unit":"teaspoon","ingredient":"salt","note":"","id":"6"}
];

// this.editableIngredients = something for object assign for the array here
```

From what I've been reading, it looks like the `array.map` method would probably be the best way, but I'm having some issues getting it right.

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53389461/object-assign-and-array-of-objects) I tried something like this: `this.editableIngredients = ingredients.flat().map(p => Object.assign(p));`

Have also tried a few different iterations based on reading [this](https://redux.js.org/recipes/using-object-spread-operator)

Comment: `Object.assign({}, ...ingredients)`? actually, no, since each ingredient has the same keys, you'll need to do something about that

Comment: @JaromandaX don't think that's going to work. You'd end up with only the last of each property. _Edit:_ you noticed 

Comment: `this.editableIngredients = ingredients.map(p => Object.assign({}, p));` ?

Comment: I guess the question is, what is the expected result

Comment: I think @Kosh has it but I'd still use the spread syntax, ie `ingredients.map(i => ({...i}))`

Comment: the issue that right now it's assigning the array by reference and not value, so when i change one variable it changes both.

Comment: do you have to use object.assign? why not just `[...oldArray, newVal]`?

Comment: I've tried `[...ingredients, this.editableIngredients]` and `this.editableIngredients = ingredients.map(i => ({...i}))` with no luck. the issue at the moment is when i use any of these, if i update an object in ingredients, it updates it in both objects (or vice versa). @Phil @Kosh @JaromandaX

Comment: @PaulDeVito that doesn't sound right at all. Could you please edit your question to add a Stack Snippet reproducing the problem

Comment: @Phil this is what i needed: `copy = [...ingredients.map(o=>Object.assign({},o))]`

Comment: No, it isn't. I cannot reproduce the problem you say you're seeing with the solution offered above ~ https://jsfiddle.net/6v8o2b71/

Comment: hmm, this one worked as well this time `this.editableIngredients = ingredients.map(i => ({...i}))`. must have had a typo before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CORRECTEDx2]
Maybe something like this:

```
copy = ingredients.map(o=>Object.assign({},o))
```

Comment: Dammit, I copied the wrong line. Here it is:
copy = [...ingredients.map(o=>Object.assign({},o))]

Comment: The spread syntax isn't going to make much of a difference since `map()` will return a new array anyway